# References using Wikipedia API

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

What actually is the Wikipedia API reference output?

I have been trying to access the numbered references and notes from Wikipedia Pages. 
Using Wikipedia API, I have started by using:

```
wikipedia.page("Page_Name").references
```

which outputs a list. But I cannot find nor see any resemblance of this list to the listed references on the Wikipedia page. 
Furthermore, every member of the outputted list is a website address in spite of many of the true references being books and papers.

Is there a way to access the references and notes using the API?
What actually is the API's reference output?
These are the mysteries.

Sorry if this has already been asked, I could not find it elsewhere, and sorry if the answer is annoyingly obvious; I haven't coded much before.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use a wrapper for the Wikipedia API? In which language? The documentation of the API can be found under https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Comment: Not so sure, am using [wikipedia 1.4.0](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/) installed as described, using Python 3.

I have seen the documentation but cannot find any information about the 'references' attribute.